# Convert Strings into my own data type with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a Haskell function that is going to to convert a string to a self-defined data type : Position, which should only consist a char of (A-H) and an Int(1-4).(i.e A1, B3, H4)

Here is the function's usage: toPosition gives Just the Position named by the string, or Nothing if the string is not a valid Position name.

Here is my try:

I defined the data type as:

```
data Position = Pos Char Int
```

I tried to run it with this in the terminal:

```
toPosition "H2"
```

GHCi returning ERROR:

```
No instance for (Show Position) arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error messages tells it all: `second` should be a `[Char]` (i.e. a `String`) but is a `Char` currently. To turn one `Char` into a one-character string you could use the function `pure`, for example.

Comment: You could also use a list literal: `read [second]`.

Comment: Or can use:  `(read (second : "") :: Int)`

Comment: Thanks guys! I updated the code but it is giving me "Not in scope: ‘toPosition’". I have no idea why this new error would occur...

Comment: Have you reloaded the file into GHCi? (e.g. `:r Position.hs`)

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Yes I had. Would this piece of code run correctly on your GHCi?

Comment: I'm getting a couple of type mismatches on line 8, i.e. your "read" line. You want to convert a `Char` into an `Int`, but `read` is designed for strings i.e. lists of chars. Since you only want to convert a single character you could just use `ord` (from `Data.Char`) and subtract the code for `0` (i.e. 48).

Comment: @PaulJohnson Thanks Paul! I will hoogle that right now!

Comment: @PaulJohnson I imported Data.Char and tried the Ord, it returns : "'No instance for (Show Position) arising from a use of ‘print’ In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it ". What does it mean?

Comment: You probably want:  `data Position = Pos Char Int   deriving   (Eq, Show)`

Comment: Also, your code should somehow be made to cover those situations where the input string has 0 or 1 character, hence does not match the `first : second : rest` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this raises an error is because it can not print the `Position`, since you did not make it an instance of `Show`. You thus can implement this as:

```
data Position = Pos Char Int deriving Show
```

But your functions are also quite complicated. You can simplify `isValidChar` and `isValidInt` with:

```
isValidChar :: Char -> Bool
isValidChar x = 'A' <= x && x <= 'H'

isValidInt :: Char -> Bool
isValidInt x = '1' <= x && x <= '4'
```

For the `toPosition` function, you can use pattern matching on a list, since a `String` is a list of `Char`s:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

toPosition :: String -> Maybe Position
toPosition [c, n]
    | isValidChar c && isValidInt n = Just (Position c (digitToInt n))
toPosition _ = Nothing
```